# How to use preg_replace() function inside mysql match() against ()

Tags: mysql, preg-replace

I just compiled preg_replace() for mysql when i trying to use preg_replace() before full text search match () against () it return mysql syntax error. My code looks similar to

```
select *, match(name, preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9A-Z]+/i', ' ', `column`)) against ('$name') as score
from files
order by score desc
```

... and triggers this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '**('/[^a-z0-9A-Z]+/i', ' ', `column`)) against
>   ('$name') as score from files** ' at line 1

Comment: `' ' infolder`? - Whatever, the error message you've carefully omitted tells the exact location of the error.

Comment: infolder is just a column name

Comment: How about you post the exact error message?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('/[^a-z0-9A-Z]+/i', ' ', `column`)) against ('search term')

Comment: @JayaPrakash - `' ' infolder` is a syntax error. I see you fixed it later.

Answer (score 2):

If we have a look at the [manual page for `MATCH...AGAINST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) we can see that `MATCH()` expects a list of columns:

> `MATCH (col1,col2,...) AGAINST (expr [search_modifier])`
>   
> [...]
>   `MATCH()` takes a comma-separated list that names the columns to be searched

However, you provide the result of a function call:

```
match(name, preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9A-Z]+/i', ' ', `column`))
```

The logic behind this is that full-text search is designed to use special indexes created on table columns to find stuff. You cannot perform full text searches in random strings.

There's a further explanation in the [Full-Text Restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html) chapter:

> The MATCH() column list must match exactly the column list in some
>   FULLTEXT index definition for the table, unless this MATCH() is IN
>   BOOLEAN MODE on a MyISAM table. For MyISAM tables, boolean-mode
>   searches can be done on nonindexed columns, although they are likely
>   to be slow.

---

**Edit:** I don't know what you have in mind but the whole point of full-text search is to perform smart fuzzy matching on natural language texts. If you tranform **"John's fiancée"** into **"Johns fiance"** before searching there's nothing that full-text can do for you. Are you sure you don't want good old exact matching?

```
WHERE preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9A-Z]+/i', ' ', `column`)='$name'
```

... or subpattern matching?

```
WHERE preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9A-Z]+/i', ' ', `column`) LIKE '%$name%'
```

Whatever, the best way to perform full-text on arbitrary strings is to get them stored into the table. It'll even improve performance for two reasons:

- You don't need to recalculate the values on every search
- You can actually use a full-text index

You can keep the value in sync manually (on every insert or update) or write a trigger to do it.

Comment: Is there any alternate to match() to use the function call inside in ti?

Comment: im looking for full-text search instead of 'like'. My string looks 'and/this/was/here' and need to be add spaces instead of '/' in the string and finally want to use match() against()

Comment: Then you definitively need to store the calculated values. If you're not willing to change your database design you can calculate and store them in a temporary table every time you query the table, but of course it won't perform nicely.